# How to make an Image object in C# to Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have a simple XAML code. It's give me an image object:

```
<Image x:Name="imageIcon" 
       Source="/Assets/Icon.png" 
       Width="160" Height="160"
       Tapped="imageIcon_Tap" />
```

I would like to ask, how can I write this code in C# for my Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx. You should always search and try before asking.

Comment: Thanks Nataniel!

Here is my solution:

            imgIcon.Name = "ImgIcon";
            imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icon.png"));
            imgIcon.Width = (int)160;
            imgIcon.Height = (int)160;
            imgIcon.Tapped += imageIcon_Tap;
            grid.Children.Add(imgIcon);

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

A tried many solution about Nataniel answer, and born my solution:

```
imgIcon.Name = "ImgIcon";
imgIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Icon.png"));
imgIcon.Width = (int)160;
imgIcon.Height = (int)160;
imgIcon.Tapped += imageIcon_Tap;
grid.Children.Add(imgIcon);
```

Thanks for Nataniel for his advice!